# Is there a spec or standard for .mobileconfig?

Tags: profile-manager, configuration-profiles

I see a lot of talk about mobileconfig files for standing up new boxes. It seems as if they're a configuration file for Profiles. Is there a spec or standard from which they're generated, or can be parsed?

Is there any where this is documented?

Answer (score 2):

Most of my searches land me on this Apple doc titled: [Configuration Profile
Reference](https://developer.apple.com/business/documentation/Configuration-Profile-Reference.pdf). I also found this tutorial which covers using the `/usr/bin/profiles` command to work with profiles on macOS. That tutorial is titled: Use [The Profiles Command In High Sierra](http://krypted.com/mac-os-x/use-profiles-command-high-sierra/).

You can use commands like this to import profiles from a file:

```
/usr/bin/profiles -I -F ~/Desktop/HawkeyesTrickshot.mobileconfig
```

The CLI tool `dscl` also received profile switches in Yosemite.

```
$ dscl <<<"help" |& grep -A6 "MCX Profile"
MCX Profile Extensions:
    -profileimport    <record path> <profile file path>
    -profiledelete    <record path> <profile specifier>
    -profilelist      <record path> [optArgs]
    -profileexport    <record path> <profile specifier> <output folder path>
    -profilehelp
```